# Inserting JsNumber into Mongo

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, playframework, casbah

When trying to insert a `MongoDBObject` that contains a `JsNumber`

```
val obj: DBObject = getDbObj // contains a "JsNumber()"
collection.insert(obj)
```

the following error occurs:

`[error] play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't serialize class scala.math.BigDecimal`

I tried to replace the `JsNumber` with an `Int`, but I got the same error.

**EDIT**

Error can be reproduced via this test code. Full code in scalatest (https://gist.github.com/kman007us/6617735)

```
val collection = MongoConnection()("test")("test")
val obj: JsValue = Json.obj("age" -> JsNumber(100))
val q = MongoDBObject("name" -> obj)
collection.insert(q)
```

Comment: Can you output an example obj so I can test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no registered handlers for Plays JSON implementation - you could add handlers to automatically translate plays Js Types to BSON types.  However, that wont handle [mongodb extended json](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json) which has a special structure dealing with non native json types eg: date and objectid translations.

An example of using this is:

```
import com.mongodb.util.JSON
val obj: JsValue = Json.obj("age" -> JsNumber(100))
val doc: DBObject = JSON.parse(obj.toString).asInstanceOf[DBObject]
```

For an example of a bson transformer see the [joda time transformer](https://github.com/mongodb/casbah/blob/master/casbah-commons/src/main/scala/conversions/ScalaConversions.scala#L183-L209).

Comment: Thanks - that worked. However, is the `asInstanceOf[DBObject]` bad practice since a run-time exception could occur?

Comment: The returned value is either a DBObject, if the string is a JSON object or array or a boxed primitive value according to the following mapping.  So theres room for a runtime exception especially where data is from an untrusted source.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that casbah driver isn't compatible with Plays's JSON implementation. If I look through the cashbah code than it seems that you must use a set of `MongoDBObject` objects to build your query. The following snippet should work.

```
val collection = MongoConnection()("test")("test")
val obj = MongoDBObject("age" -> 100)
val q = MongoDBObject("name" -> obj)
collection.insert(q)
```

If you need the compatibility with Play's JSON implementation then use [ReactiveMongo](http://reactivemongo.org/) and [Play-ReactiveMongo](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/Play-ReactiveMongo).

**Edit**

Maybe this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/doitian/5555040) can help to convert `JsValue` objects into `MongoDBObject` objects.